# How to get the file size of a generated pdf (in bytes) angular using jspdf and html2canvas

Tags: angular, jspdf, html2canvas

I am currently converting an html page to a PDF using html2canvas and jspdf.
I want to retrieve the file size in bytes to display it on the screen for the user. If anyone knows a handy method, it would be helpfull. Thanks for help :)

Here the code to convert the html to the PDF :

```
 exportPDF() {
const data = document.getElementById("content");
html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
  // Few necessary setting options
  const imgWidth = 208;
  const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;

  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4"); // A4 size page of PDF
  const position = 0;
  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, "PNG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  pdf.save("file.pdf"); // Generated PDF
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output it using blob, like this.

```js
  let blob = pdf.output("blob");
  console.log(blob.size);
  pdf.save("file.pdf"); // Generated PDF
```